# How debug vercel's server rendering error on production

Tags: next.js, vercel

I got this error on production and dev while locally it is fine.

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {Name}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    at nO (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:63401)
```

how to get access to the file of app-page.runtime.prod.js?